# For loop in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, loops

I have two question. First question: Python script that shows me the precipitation for a certain period.For example, I'm getting an initial year-month and a final year-month.
**Initial:**
year:2000
month:3 
**Final**
year1:2005
month:4
Now, instead of seeing: 
2000/3,2000/4,2000/5,2000/6..........2005/1,2005/2,2005/3,2005/4
she works like this(look in the hooked picture):
*2000/3, 2000/4, 2001/3, 2001/4........2005/3,2005/4*.
I want to work for me like the first case.

```
def period_month_prec(year,month,year1,month1):    
   for i in range (year,year1+1,1):
        for j in range(month,month1+1,1):
             ......................
```

Second question: How to write the output(picture) from the script in csv.file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcWXB.png)

This is what my views.py script looks like , which saves me only the first result:

```
def monthly_period(request):

if request.method == "POST" :
    form = PeriodMonthlyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        year = data.get('year')
        month = data.get('month')
        year1 = data.get('year1')
        month1 = data.get('month1')
        lon = data.get('lon')
        lat = data.get ('lat')
        inter = data.get('inter')

        point = period_month_prec(year,month,year1,month1,lon,lat)
        args = {'point':point}
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/txt')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="precipitation.txt"'
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow([point])
        return response

else:

    form = PeriodMonthlyForm()
    active_period_monthly = True

return render (request, 'carpatclimapp/home.html',{'form':form, 'active_period_monthly': active_period_monthly})
```

Comment: please don't write two questions in one. Create two questions. Also show what you have in your for-loops that doesn't work, it's not clear what you're doing wrong (you shouldn't ask us to write code for you). Finally you're showing us a view that processes POST data (one point) and writes it to csv format, how do you expect it to write more than one row? Explain what's being POSTed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have forms like this:
[Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSSJe.png)

You set initial values(red color) and end interval(blue color). For this given interval, the lon and lat are defined for the point in which we want to perform interpolation. When you press the submit button, it starts with interpolation for a defined period. The loop problem is because it works only for the defined months (we see from the 2nd picture that it only works in the interval 1-6) but not for 7,8,9,10,11,12 months between these years.

*Initial*: **year**:2000, **month**:3
*Final*: **year1**:2001, **month**:4
for this she's doing it like this: 2000/3,2000/4,2001/3,2001/4

I do not want that, I want this: 2000/3,2000/4,2000/5,2000/6,2000/7.....2000/12,2001/1,2001/2,2001/3,2001/4.

this is me code :

```
def period_month_prec(year,month,year1,month1,lon,lat):

cnx = sqlite3.connect(DB1)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

table = 'monthly'
year = int(year)
year1 = int(year1)
month = int(month)
month1 = int(month1)

for i in range (year,year1+1,1):
    for j in range(month,month1+1,1):

        query = '''
            SELECT  dates, cell, prec FROM %s WHERE dates = "%s-%s" ;
            ''' % (table,i,j)

        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnx)

        tacka = '''SELECT id, lon, lat,country,altitude FROM %s;''' % 'grid1'
        grid1 = pd.read_sql_query(tacka, cnx)

        podaci = pd.merge(df,grid1,left_on='cell',right_on='id')
        podaci_a = podaci.drop(['cell','id','country','altitude'],axis=1)
        lon_n = podaci_a['lon'].values
        lat_n = podaci_a['lat'].values
        prec =podaci_a['prec'].values

        x_masked, y_masked, prec_p = remove_nan_observations(lon_n, lat_n, prec)

        xy = np.vstack([x_masked,y_masked]).T
        xi = ([lon,lat])


        inter_point = interpolate_to_points(xy,prec_p,xi, interp_type='linear'

        return (i,j,lon,lat,inter_point)
```

The results that come out look like this:
[loop with calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18xY4.png)

The second question was how to save these results(2nd picture) in the csv file, how to write correctly views.py. Currently she looks like this :

```
def monthly_period(request):

if request.method == "POST" :
    form = PeriodMonthlyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        year = data.get('year')
        month = data.get('month')
        year1 = data.get('year1')
        month1 = data.get('month1')
        lon = data.get('lon')
        lat = data.get ('lat')
        inter = data.get('inter')

        point = period_month_prec(year,month,year1,month1,lon,lat)
        args = {'point':point}
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/txt')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="precipitation.txt"'
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow([point])
        return response

else:

    form = PeriodMonthlyForm()
    active_period_monthly = True

return render (request, 'carpatclimapp/home.html',{'form':form, 'active_period_monthly': active_period_monthly})
```

I hope I'm a little clearer now